# Is there a CherryPy debug toolbar?

Tags: python, debugging, cherrypy

Is it possible to have a debugging toolbar for CherryPy like django-debug-toolbar for Django and pyramid_debug_toolbar for Pyramid?

I want to be able to inspect the stacktrace when an exception occurs without using an IDE with breakpoints.

If anybody can help or point to me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up using pdb instead.